Find a parameter to return minimum of the function of several variables
I have two functions $f_1(n,x)$ and $f_2(n,x)$, and I want them to look similar on the given range $n\in[1,20]$. I can only vary the parameter $x$.
In other words I have a function $F(n,x)=f_1(n,x)-f_2(n,x)$ and want to find $x$ returning its minimum along the range $n\in[1,20]$ ($\sum_{n=1}^{20}F(n,x)$).
Does Mathematica have any routines to do so (seems it relates to Least squares) ? What I need to do to fit a function by another one on the given range $n\in[1,20]$ varying only x ? I tried to find the solution, but what I found so far (Minimize and MinValue) was for a function of a single variable. I am sure what I am looking for is trivial, and there is such a function in Mathematica, but I am stacked now.
Expressions are the following (in fact they are way complicated):
f1=1./((1 - E^(-x n))^(1/6) n^(1/3));
f2=1./((1 - E^(-x n))^(1/5) n^(1/2));


The problem is unbounded (it's always important to check boundaries in optimization) so a global minimum exists in the limit as $x \rightarrow -\infty$:
f1 = 1./((1 - E^(-x  n))^(1/6)  n^(1/3));
f2 = 1./((1 - E^(-x  n))^(1/5)  n^(1/2));

diff = f1 - f2;

Assuming[1 <= n <= 20, Limit[diff, x -> -Infinity]]

(*0*)


If this was just given as an example however, one thing we can do is use the fact that $ z ~ z^* = |z|^2 $ to give us our squared error and minimize:
diffSq = diff * Conjugate[diff];
objective = Sum[diffSq, {n, 20}];
NMinimize[objective, x]

(*{9.02118*10^-40, {x -> -269.711}}*)



I may introduce the following algorithm, which interprets and may explain the method of minimization:


% Define the functions
    \begin{verbatim}
    f1[n_, x_] := 1./((1 - E^(-x n))^(1/6) n^(1/3));
    f2[n_, x_] := 1./((1 - E^(-x n))^(1/5) n^(1/2));
    
        % Define the objective function
        objective[x_] := Sum[Abs[f1[n, x] - f2[n, x]], {n, 1, 20}];
        
        % Find the value of x that minimizes the objective function
        result = NMinimize[objective[x], x]
        
        % Display the result
        result
        \end{verbatim}

Here is the Mathematica code which interprets the above algorithm:
(* Define the functions *)
f1[n_, x_] := 1./((1 - E^(-x n))^(1/6) n^(1/3));
f2[n_, x_] := 1./((1 - E^(-x n))^(1/5) n^(1/2));

(* Define the objective function *)
objective[x_] := Sum[Abs[f1[n, x] - f2[n, x]], {n, 1, 20}];

(* Find the value of x that minimizes the objective function *)
result = NMinimize[objective[x], x]

(* Display the result *)
result


